# Need help about generic types and Objects

Tags: java, generics

I have created generic SingleLinkedList to store my own created objects from the class I wrote.
The problem is I don't know how to display that objects in a generic SingleLinkedList.

I tried T.getClass(). etc but I failed.

Thanks.

Edit:

```
if(head.getData() instanceof Company) 
    {
        if(head!=null) 
        {
            Node<T> temp=head;
            while(temp!=null) 
            {
                Company comp=(Company) temp.getData();
                System.out.println(comp.getName());
                temp=temp.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the current statements that is working for my case
I'm curious about is there a another approaches for this kind of intention.

Thanks for the answer below,I used "instanceof"

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: "I don't know how to display that objects in a generic SingleLinkedList" What exactly does this mean? Do you want create a string representing the contents of the list akin to `List.toString()` (e.g. showing `{1,2,3}` for `List.of(1,2,3)`, or do you want to display the type of the generic parameter?

Comment: My knowledge about generics types are not much but I have seen some notations like Class<T> and ?,I am currently checking websites,

Comment: My question was to insert object(which created from Class) to Generic SLL.

Comment: and display that objects but I can't write sysout(temp.getData()),it gaves me the something about memory that I don't know currently.

Comment: "I tried T.getClass(). etc" indicates you have written some code. Please show it to us, together with a description what you want it to do and what output/error message you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach isn't really "generic", as you have to add code similar to the above for `Company` for all possible data classes.

An actually generic approach would be to provide a `Function<T, String>` (or similar), in order that you can convert the data in the list to a thing you can print, somehow.

Assuming this is inside the `SingleLinkedList<T>` class, you can change you code to (*):

```
// I said Function<T, String> above, but actually you only need a
// function which will accept a T and gives you back any object.
void printList(Function<? super T, ?> toStringFn) {
  Node<T> temp=head;
  while(temp!=null) 
  {
    System.out.println(toStringFn.apply(temp.getData()));
    temp=temp.getNext();
  }
}
```

and then call this like:

```
companyList.printList(Company::getName);
```

---

(*) I would say a `for` loop might be neater of writing the method:

```
void printList(Function<? super T, String> toStringFn) {
  for (Node<T> temp=head; temp != null; temp = temp.getNext()) {
    System.out.println(toStringFn.apply(temp.getData()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I should focus on documentations before writing generic classes

Answer (score -1):

You can use instanceof.

```
if(t instanceof YourObject){}
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks it has worked for my case,but I'm curios about is there another ways to get same results as this.